# Use HTML for labels in D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have a simple example of a D3 collapsible tree, mostly copied and pasted from the examples in the tutorial. I'm trying to see if I can replace the way labels are being displayed, which is currently text, with HTML to allow me to put some formatting on the labels. I've had a look around and seen that HTML can be used with svg:foreignObject, but I'm not quite sure how to do it in this case.  Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Rutgers",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Rutgers New Brunswick",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Rutgers School of Arts and Science",
          },
          {
            "name": "Rutgers Business School",
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Rutgers Newark",
      },
    ]
  },
];



var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var line = d3.svg.line()
             .x(function(d){ return d.x; })
             .y(function(d){return d.y; });

    function lineData(d){
        var points = [
            {x: d.source.y, y: d.source.x},
            {x: d.target.y, y: d.target.x}
        ]
        return line(points);
    }


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  root = treeData[0];
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;


  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes�
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links�
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return lineData({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", lineData);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return lineData({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I wouldn't resort to using `foreignObject` unless you are desperate (there's no IE support).  What sort of formatting do you need to do?

Comment: Mark, there's going to be a lot more data at each node which I will want to display in a formatted way, which could be tabular data, or list data.  Is there a simple way of substituting nodeEnter.append("text") with nodeEnter.append("html")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here there's a Mike example: [gist.github.com/mbostock/1424037](http://gist.github.com/mbostock/1424037)

And here your example: [jsbin.com/wibuhirohe/edit?html,output](http://jsbin.com/wibuhirohe/edit?html,output). Just replace the html with your content

```
nodeEnter.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
  .append("xhtml:body")
    .style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'")
    .html("<h1>An HTML Foreign Object in SVG</h1>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          Donec eu enim quam. Quisque nisi risus, sagittis quis tempor
          nec, aliquam...
```

If you need more style you can add a class like so:

```
nodeEnter.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("class", "myBeautifulText")
```

then define on `<style>`

```
.myBeautifulText {
    font-size: 1em;
    .....
    }
.myBeautifulText > h1 {
       .....
    }
.myBeautifulText > p {
       .......
    }
```

> As @Mark mention it, there's no IE support